# Ruby - Difference between if and if then statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements, control-flow

In Ruby, I know that control flow statements typically follow the following pattern.

```
If statement
  do something
else
  do something else
end
```

From my experiences that was the only pattern I noticed. However, when looking at code on a website, I saw something new that looked similar (if-then). I've never seen that before and would appreciate any explanations.

```
if statement then
  do something
else
  do something else
end
```

I'd like to know what the difference between those code blocks is. They seem to do the same thing.

Edit: I would like to clarify, I'm talking about an if then line followed by a block, not if then on one line. Please keep that in mind

Comment: Looked at that, didn't get my answer. This is different. In my example, I have the then statement on the same line as the if statement FOLLOWED by a block. I don't have the if/then statement on the same line. Thanks for your help though

Comment: I encourage you to reread the link because it discusses *exactly that* at great length.

Comment: So what I gather is then is optional?

Answer (score 2):

The "then" syntax is used when you want to use the "if" expression on one line.  In this case there needs to be a separator to ensure the line is understood by the interpreter.

See here [Ruby If Syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures)